# Interpretation of PES spectra

Tags: analytical-chemistry, photochemistry

> [image]
>
> Given that both elements are in the same period, what information from the PES spectra indicates that oxygen would have a smaller atomic radius?
> (A) The number of peaks
> (B) The intensity of the peaks
> (C) Binding energy of the peaks
> (D) A and C
> (E) B and C

Recently my chemistry teacher and I had a dispute over a test question, what would be the correct answer?

Personally, while I do agree with the fact that binding energy clearly answers the question, I also believe that the intensity of the peaks could also indicate that oxygen has a smaller radius than nitrogen, given that they are in the same period.

This is because intensity indicates the number of electrons, which indicates the number of protons, which indicates that oxygen would have a greater effective nuclear charge, and thus a smaller radius. As a result, my answer was both B and C, contrary to my teacher's answer of simply C.